# Add User License with Google Reseller API

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-reseller-api

As company, we have Google Reseller account. We want to add a form in our website for our customers to buy new licenses (change seats count) easily.

According to our scenario:

1) Customer opens our webpage (lets say ourdomain.com/reseller/addLicense)
2) Customer enters thier domain name and how many licences they want to add in proper input areas and click a button like AddLicences.
3) Google OAuth page opens and customer allows access.
4) Customer sees a status screen if the operation is successfull or failed.

This is the main idea. But I couldn't figure out how to begin. Should I write it with Javascript? If yes, how?

Do you have any ideas? I hope it is clear.

Comment: Let me know if this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to utilize the Google Apps License Manager API to assign arbitrary resold licenses (e.g. Storage addons, Vault).

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/